# Mongodb average size jumps disk usage doubles

Tags: python, mongodb

I have made a little benchmark to enlighten a phenomenon that i don't quite understand:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(w=0)  # non blocking writes, opti

db = client['test_mongo']
posts = db.posts

values = {str(i): 'value' for i in range(0, 71)}


posts.insert_many([
    {
        'a': 'a',  # average size 2031 when uncommented, 1007 else
        **values
     }
    for i in range(0, 10_000)])

stats = db.command('dbstats')
print(stats['avgObjSize'], stats['storageSize']/1024/1024)
db.command('dropDatabase')
```

When i have a certain amount of data, if i add just one more the storage usage
jumps.. and in this case doubles, taking from 10 to 21 mo when just one key added.

Is there any explanations ? I am running on mongodb 2.6.10

Comment: It's some time that I don't use mongo, but as far as I remember what you see is a consequence of mongodb pre-allocating disk space on a block basis (instead of allocating the space for every document, it allocate one block of 10 or more Mb and when it is full it allocate one or  more block)

Comment: Ok, but then why doubles the document size (from 1kb to 2). I tried different document sizes, the smallest is 49, then 112, then 240.. why such huge jumps in documents/block sizes ?

Comment: I fact it doubles each times the limit is reached

Comment: It seems that mongodb pre-allocate the disk space doubling each time until it hit the 2Gb limit. From this point on it allocate always 2 Gb.